# render firebase data in the backend angular 17 ssr

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm using firebase for an angular 17 projects and I have activated the ssr module in the creation of the project, now I get the data from firebase but it isn't rendering when I open Page Source, I know for http you use `withHttpTransferCacheOptions` but how I'm going to do it for firebase call?

```
const productsCollection = collection(this.fs, 'products')
const productQuery = query(productsCollection, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), where("createdAt", ">=", Calendar.getCurrentWeekDate(now).weekStart), where("createdAt", "<=", Calendar.getCurrentWeekDate(now).weekEnd))
return collectionData(productQuery, { idField: 'id'})
```